# Facebook: page_fan_country insight doesn't work anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I want to get the number of page likers grouped by country.

But the Graph API query `/v2.1/ladygaga/insights/page_fans_country` doesn't return any interesting data anymore.

It seems to work only with an access token of an old app created before April 2014. When I try to change the version `v1.0`, `v2.0`there is no change.

I never read that Facebook has deprecated this feature.

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/insights) still says:

> Any valid access token can be used for publicly available metrics.

Do I make something wrong or is the `page_fan_country` not a public metric anymore?